# Python webbrowser wrapper websocket?

Tags: javascript, python, browser, websocket

I am develope a browser NFC soloution for my raspberry pi. What I develop a java applet in a Chrome browser. The java applet is working with my nfc reader. Everytime a tag my card he will call a javascript function and send my Card ID to this javascript function. There is a alert with my card ID.

Java is really heavy and cost a lot of memory. What I do like is use python instead of java. The python script needs to de the same as the java applet.

1. Read my NFC card
2. Send the Card id to an javascript function
3. Give a alert with my tag ID.
4. wait for the next card and do the same... go to 1

What i discover was a python websocket like http://autobahn.ws/ It will put up a webserver easy. Put the problem I face is that the Python script cannot call directly a javascript function. The javascriopt function can call a python function but not the way around.

My question will be. Where can I find the soloution to call everytime the javascript function when i tag my NFC card with a Python script

NFC python is http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Autobahn you would *subscribe* to a topic "NFC-Tag-Read" in your browser JS and *publish* tag event to that topic from your Python on Pi.